# Decoding [String: AnyObject] JSON dictionary in using Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4, decodable

How can one decode a dictionary of type [String: AnyObject], when AnyObject is not decodable?

The error I get is:

> Fatal error: Dictionary does not conform to
>   Decodable because AnyObject does not conform to Decodable

Is there any way to bypass this?

I cannot use a dictionary of type [String: String] because some of the values can also be Int or Doubles.

EDIT: here's a chunk of the code, I'm using Alamofire5 to make the request:

```
private static func performRequest<T: Decodable>(path: String, method: HTTPMethod, params: [String: Any]?, completion: @escaping (Result<T>) -> Void) -> DataRequest? {
........
 return Alamofire.request(urlFromString(path), method: method, parameters: requestParams, headers: [:]).validate()
            .responseJSONDecodable { (response: DataResponse<T>) in
                completion(response.result)
            }
}
```

Comment: Add your code work.

Comment: Decode the dictionary into a struct. By the way a JSON dictionary in Swift 3+ is always `[String:Any]` not `[String: AnyObject]`

Comment: @vadian I don't want to create a struct for each request of this type, I just want to decode as a dictionary and take my info from there

Comment: `Decodable` relies on concrete types. `Any(Object)` is not supported. The alternative is traditional `JSONSerialization`